# While building LLVM got errors in AlignOf.h

Tags: c++, llvm

I get multiple errors while building LLVM from official source files with cmake and Visual Studio 14 2015, and can't figure out why this happens, what is the reason these errors arise?

> D:\LLVM\build\llvm\include\llvm/Support/AlignOf.h(57):
>   error C2988: unrecognizable template declaration/definition
>   [D:\LLVM\build\build\lib\System\LLVMSystem.vcxproj]
>   D:\LLVM\build\llvm\include\llvm/Support/AlignOf.h(57):
>   error C2059: syntax error: 'alignof' [D:\LLVM\build\build\lib\System\LLVMSystem.vcxproj]
>   D:\LLVM\build\llvm\include\llvm/Support/AlignOf.h(59):
>   error C2143: syntax error: missing ';' before '}'
>   [D:\LLVM\build\build\lib\System\LLVMSystem.vcxproj]

This is code in the AlignOf.h file:

```
#ifndef LLVM_SUPPORT_ALIGNOF_H
#define LLVM_SUPPORT_ALIGNOF_H

namespace llvm {

template <typename T>
struct AlignmentCalcImpl {
  char x;
  T t;
private:
  AlignmentCalcImpl() {} // Never instantiate.
};

/// AlignOf - A templated class that contains an enum value representing
///  the alignment of the template argument.  For example,
///  AlignOf<int>::Alignment represents the alignment of type "int".  The
///  alignment calculated is the minimum alignment, and not necessarily
///  the "desired" alignment returned by GCC's __alignof__ (for example).  Note
///  that because the alignment is an enum value, it can be used as a
///  compile-time constant (e.g., for template instantiation).
template <typename T>
struct AlignOf {
  enum { Alignment =
         static_cast<unsigned int>(sizeof(AlignmentCalcImpl<T>) - sizeof(T)) };

  enum { Alignment_GreaterEqual_2Bytes = Alignment >= 2 ? 1 : 0 };
  enum { Alignment_GreaterEqual_4Bytes = Alignment >= 4 ? 1 : 0 };
  enum { Alignment_GreaterEqual_8Bytes = Alignment >= 8 ? 1 : 0 };
  enum { Alignment_GreaterEqual_16Bytes = Alignment >= 16 ? 1 : 0 };

  enum { Alignment_LessEqual_2Bytes = Alignment <= 2 ? 1 : 0 };
  enum { Alignment_LessEqual_4Bytes = Alignment <= 4 ? 1 : 0 };
  enum { Alignment_LessEqual_8Bytes = Alignment <= 8 ? 1 : 0 };
  enum { Alignment_LessEqual_16Bytes = Alignment <= 16 ? 1 : 0 };

};

/// alignof - A templated function that returns the mininum alignment of
///  of a type.  This provides no extra functionality beyond the AlignOf
///  class besides some cosmetic cleanliness.  Example usage:
///  alignof<int>() returns the alignment of an int.
template <typename T>
static inline unsigned alignof() { return AlignOf<T>::Alignment; }

} // end namespace llvm
#endif
```

Comment: Can you even build llvm using the microsoft cl.exe compiler?

Comment: While building I'm following the official llvm guide "Building LLVM with CMake" http://llvm.org/docs/CMake.html, and getting 'unrecognizable template declaration' in AlignOf.h, any clues why does the problem arise?

Answer (score 0):

I think that this is mainly due to discrepancy in alignof and alignOf in the header files.

This fixed the issue for me:
http://llvm.org/viewvc/llvm-project?view=revision&revision=117774